# How to use $refs in template - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a input with attribute "ref" and I don't want to use v-model

```
<div class="form-group m-b-40">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ref="name"  required> 
</div>
 {{showInput}}
```

I want to show my input value automatically. I do this

```
 methods: {
       showInput: function () {
            this.$refs.name.value
        },
    }
```

but it isn't updated.

Comment: *"I don't want to use v-model"* why?  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @zero298 At first I get value from api. then user can edit this value. before save it i must show this changed value

Comment: I don't understand why that matters.  Please explain exactly what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and what isn't working.  Provide as much context as you can.  The [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page will probably help you understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `value` of a `ref` isn't an observable object unless it's bound to the component instance:

```
data() {
    return {
        name: ''
    }
}
```

Then give your `input` a `:value="name"` and now it has an observer attached to it

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you want to do,but the way you are doing it seems to be wrong.Anyway,you said *i dont want to use* `v-model`.

I am going to show you how to do it without v-model,you can fetch the input value from api(you have to write your own code for this) and set it to input:

```
 <template>
    <div>
      <div class="form-group m-b-40">
        <input type="text" :value="text" @input="updateValue"> 
        <hr>
      </div>
      The input value is: {{text}}
    </div>
 </template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        text: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchFromApi()
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(value) {
        let newValue = value.target.value
        this.text = newValue
    },
    fetchFromApi() {
        //write the code to get from API the input value and then:
      this.text = 'input value' //set the input value
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[See it in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/ve3ttmm9/)